# Calling javascript in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, wpf, silverlight

I have an Silverlight app that makes a communication with my webcam to take photos.

**Silverlight Code**

```
protected void photoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.src.CaptureImageCompleted += (s, a) =>
    {
        this.lastSnapshot = a.Result;
        this.snapshot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.snapshot.Source = this.lastSnapshot;
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("SalvaFoto");                
        this.src.Stop();
    };

    src.CaptureImageAsync();
}
```

**ASPX Where I call my Silverlight Application**

```
            var htmlEmbedSilverlight = "<div id='silverlightControlHost'> "
                    + "<object data='data:application/x-silverlight-2,' type='application/x-silverlight-2' width='550px' height='250px'> "
                    + "<param name='source' value='../../ClientBin/FotoEmprestimoChave.xap'/> "
                    + "<param name='onError' value='onSilverlightError' /> "
                    + "<param name='background' value='white' /> "
                    + "<param name='minRuntimeVersion' value='4.0.60310.0' /> "
                    + "<param name='autoUpgrade' value='true' /> "
                    + "<param name='InitParams' value='chave_id=" + data + "' /> "
                    + "<a href='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0' style='text-decoration:none'> "
                    + "<img src='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376' alt='Get Microsoft Silverlight' style='border-style:none'/> "
                    + "</a> "
                    + "</object><iframe id='_sl_historyFrame' style='visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px'></iframe></div>";
            $("#tiraFotoSilverlight").html(htmlEmbedSilverlight);
```

**Problem**

When I try execute an `Javascript` in the current `ASPX` page with `HtmlPage.Windows.Invoke("javascript_method");` doesn't work.

I'm doing something wrong ?

I've also try the following code but without success

```
protected void photoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.src.CaptureImageCompleted += (s, a) =>
    {
        this.lastSnapshot = a.Result;
        this.snapshot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.snapshot.Source = this.lastSnapshot;

        HtmlElement Script = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("script");
        Script.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        Script.SetProperty("text", "$(document).ready(function () { alert('hi'); });");

        this.src.Stop();
    };

    src.CaptureImageAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new Silverlight/Javascript, but where I have done this, I needed to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("SalvaFoto");
    });
```